# The IAP server-side module in php

Tags: module, in-app-purchase, codenameone, server-side

My hired service does not allow JAVA application to run at the service provider. Therefore, IAP server module must be implemented in php.

I wrote php code. I think I can implement it. But if someone has already done it, I would save some development time.

Please inform me is there public IAP server-side module PHP implementation?

Comment: A question like this probably will be downvoted, because it is too much generic. However, you can setup a cheap VPS (at the cost of few euros/dollars per months) to run Java applications on server side. For the "In App Purchase", there is a lesson of Shai Almog in the Codenme One Academy. There are also these three tutorials on the Codename One blog, made by Steve Hannah : https://www.codenameone.com/blog/intro-to-in-app-purchase.html

Comment: I'm afraid we don't have a version in PHP offhand, you can probably port our Java code to PHP

Answer (score 1):

IAP servers have a huge range of complexity depending on the needs of your business. The simplest implementation would be just a receipt validator, and there are a handful open-source examples of this on Github (https://github.com/aporat/store-receipt-validator)

Since you mentioned saving development time, there are services such as [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/) that manage a complete IAP server for you.